# php 7 with openssl verion

Tags: php, windows, openssl

I installed php 7.0 on my windows server.

PHP shows:

> openssl
>   OpenSSL support  enabled
>   OpenSSL Library Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
>   OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013

I did update `openssl` on my windows system but it does not seem recognized by php.

How can I upgrade the `openssl` version inside php to a later version say 1.0.2?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The build of php 7.0.4 at http://windows.php.net ships with OpenSSL 1.0.2g

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: thanks for the update. I am actually coming from a development angle but you are right this specific question is more installation.

Comment: thanks VolkerK for the info. Very helpful.